# Add all possible two-way interactions between two sets of variables - R

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following specification:

```
glm(death ~ age + black + hisp + other + rich + middle, family = binomial("probit"), data=data)
```

Is there a straightforward way to add all two-way interactions between the "ethnicity group" (black, hisp, and other) and the "income group" (rich, middle).  So the interactions would be black*rich, black*middle, hisp*rich, and so on.

Comment: `interaction` or `:`

Comment: It's not clear to me how to use either of those for "grouped" permutations like described above.  Interaction computes all 2-way interactions.  I don't want interactions between the race variables, only between those two sets.

Comment: You need to melt your data into "ethnicity" and "income" factor columns. I'm not wholly sure how they play with `glm`, but I've seen formulas with `:` before that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula interface lets you do that easily with the `^`-operator where you could construct all the 2way interactions from two factor variables by `(ethnicity + incgrp)^2` , but that only applies if you use the R factor conventions. It appears you are attempting to circumvent the proper use of formulas and factors by instead doing SAS-style dummy variable creation. For your situation, you might try:

```
glm(death ~ age + (black + hisp + other)*( rich + middle), family = binomial("probit"), data=data)
```

The `formula` interpretation uses both `^` and `*` to construct interactions. They loose their conventional mathematical meaning. See `?formula`

Answer (score 1):

Consider pasting all combinations inside the formula:

```
vars1 <-  c('black', 'hisp', 'other')
vars2 <-  c('rich', 'middle')
interactions <- outer(vars1, vars2, function(x,y){paste0(x,'*',y)})
intjoin <- paste(interactions, collapse=" + ")
#[1] "black*rich + hisp*rich + other*rich + black*middle + hisp*middle + other*middle"

model <- glm(paste0('death ~ age + black + hisp + other + rich + middle + ', intjoin), 
             family = binomial("probit"), data=data)
```